# How to convert a comma separated string field to array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a string field in a mongodb collection which holds values in comma separated string. Now i want change the type of that particular field to array. As the collection contains 30 million records, would the below query have any performance implications?

```
    db.getCollection("collectionName").find().forEach( function (el) {
         el.NameofFieldToChangeType = el.NameofFieldToChangeType.split(',');
         db.databaseName.save(el);
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering the amount of data, I would definitely run this directly on the server. Here is an example that works to use as a guide. It will replace the `names` field with a new array from the `$split`.

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
    [
        { "$addFields": { 
            "names": { "$split": [ "$names", "," ] } 
        }},
        {$out:"collectionName"}
    ]
)
```

Comment: @matthPen this code has been tested and verified against v 4.0.4 before posting the example. Not sure why you feel this doesn't work.

Comment: db.databaseName.save(el);  => never applied with your aggregation. You just transform data on query response, but never persists these data in db.

Comment: But you're right on the transformation itself, and about the amount of data.

Comment: You mean data is updated in your database after your aggregation query? In other words, if you performs your aggregation, you can do a find() after that and get array instead of string for "names" field? Curious to see that wihtout $out stage...

Comment: @@matthPen, apologies, but you were correct, I must have viewed the output results in a hurry. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: no problem, Everybody faced that kind of mistake at least once. :)

Answer (score 2):

Before 4.2, you have to use aggregation with an $out stage to achieve what you need.

```
db.collectionName.aggregate(
    [
        { "$addFields": { 
            "NameofFieldToChangeType": { "$split": [ "$NameofFieldToChangeType", "," ] } 
        }},
        {$out:"collectionName"}
    ]
)
```

Starting with 4.2, you can use updateMany with aggregation in update param, like this :

```
db.collectionName.updateMany(
  {},
  [{$addFields:{"NameofFieldToChangeType": { "$split": [ "$NameofFieldToChangeType", "," ]}}
  }]
)
```